# iOS kind of Around me navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, augmented-reality

I'm developing a location-aware application and I need a kind of "Around Me" function that shows the closest points of interest (POIs) to the user. What I'm trying to do is to show the POIs in a table view where there's written the name of the POI, the distance from the device location and I would like also to show an arrow that point to the direction to reach the POI as shown in the following picture.

[image]

I know the bearing (angle) between the user's location and the POI's location, the problem is when the user changes his heading and I need to update the bearing about the two locations. Does anyone has a suggestion about the formula? What I tried at the moment is to get the magnetic heading from the user location and subtract the initial bearing computed in order to do:

```
double relativeDirectionToCoordinate = degreesToRadians(magnHeadingDeg) - directionToCoordinate;

cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(relativeDirectionToCoordinate);
```

where ***magnHeadingDeg*** is the magnetic heading of the user location transformed then in radians and ***directionToCoordinate*** is the initial bearing of the two locations.

This approach seems not correct, so please if you have some advice I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: how do you get the bearing between the user's location and the POI's? And try locationBearing - heading instead. And if you are not in portrait mode don't forget to set you heading orientation

Comment: I've found an implementation of the method and basically what it does is                                                         `float possibleAzimuth = (M_PI * .5f) - atan(latitudinalDifference / longitudinalDifference);
    
    if (longitudinalDifference > 0) 
        return possibleAzimuth;
    else if (longitudinalDifference < 0)
        return possibleAzimuth + M_PI; 
    else if (latitudinalDifference < 0)
        return M_PI; 
    
    return 0.0f;` I guessed the landscape mode affects the orientation